# Modes in a subwavelength-diameter optical fiber

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, fiber-optics, applied-physics

I would love to know about propagation modes in a subwavelength-diameter optical fiber. For example: There is an optical fiber (core diameter = 0.7 μm), the refractive index of the core (n1 = 2.1), the cladding is air (refractive index n2 = 1). What happens if light (λ = 1.5 μm) is transmitted in this fiber ? How many propagation modes ? Is optical energy lost between the output and the input of this fiber ? 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is given as part of my answer to your other similar question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/356562/26076).

**In a dielectric waveguide**, nothing special happens: the field spreads out so that it is significantly different from zero over a diameter that is much greater than the core diameter. There is still no loss for a straight fiber even if the core is arbitrarily small. However, the mode becomes more and more weakly guided: theoretically lossless for a straight fiber but more and more subject to loss, through coupling into the radiation field, when the fiber is bent. For a very small core, even the mildest bend curvatures lead to significant loss.

Chapter 23 of Snyder and Love, "Optical Waveguide Theory" describes this phenomenon in detail. The propagation constant for a bend step index fiber has a real (attenuating) part with a term  given by (See Eq. 23-12 in Snyder and Love):

$$\exp\left(-\frac{4\,R_c\,\Delta\,W^3}{3\,\rho\,V^2}\right)$$

where $\rho$ is the core radius, $R_c$ the bend radius, $\Delta$ and $V$ are the waveguide parameters and $W$ the cladding eigenvalue for the fundamental mode. This quantity increases swiftly with decreasing bend radius, and the ratio $\Delta\,W^3/V^2$ measures the guiding strength: for small cores, this is large which means even mild bends lead to high loss. For large cores and large core-cladding index differences, this ratio is small, and it takes a very tight bend to beget significant loss.

**In a metal clad waveguide**, as in my other answer, the field vectors for the fundamental mode vary with radial position $r$ and axial position $z$ within the fiber like $J_0(k_\perp\,r)\,\exp\left(i\,\sqrt{k^2\,n^2-k_\perp^2}\,z\right)$ and we must have $k_\perp\,r_0 = \omega_{0\,1}\approx 2.405$, where $\omega_{0\,1}$ is the first zero of the Bessel function and $r_0$ the core radius, to fulfill the field continuity boundary conditions. This sets a minimum core radius $r_0$ that one can have for a propagating field; this minimum radius is $r_{min}\approx 2.405\,\lambda/(2\,\pi\,n)$. For $1.5{\rm \mu m}$ wavelength (in freespace) light and a core refractive index of 1.5, the minimum possible mode field diameter is about 770nm. If the core is any smaller, then $\sqrt{k^2\,n^2-k_\perp^2}$ is imaginary, *all* modes of the metal clad waveguide are cut off and propagation becomes evanescent, *i.e.* non power transporting. This is the mechanism that stops EM waves getting through subwavelength holes in conductive materials of any significant thickness: this is how the mesh on a microwave oven door stops leakage even though we can see through the mesh.